# How to change toolbar color in Property Grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, colors, propertygrid

Can't find a color property in PropertyGrid form to change THIS color
[image: that color, can't change it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with `PropertyGrid.BackColor` ? You're looking for `BackColor` property.

```
propertyGrid1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

Comment: @Greag.Deay I was confused first looking at question, thinking that is there any other property exist.. :)